# How to refactor a "library of functions" class that is tightly coupled with the business objects?

Tags: php, oop, refactoring, decoupling

I have a `Calc` class that I think was improperly placed in the codebase I am working with.  For the class structure see code below.

Currently

- `Spec` class acts as a storage of data, similar to C struct
- `Calc` class is a library of computational functions class that is instantiated as part of other classes, whenever those classes need to do some computation.  `Calc` class also houses `Spec` class, so that it can do computations using variables of `Spec`.
- `Plot` class is an example of a business object representing a graph.
- `Controller` class is a business object representing a controller of sorts in my application, where some computations are made and are displayed in text for user page "View", and a graph is also created which is also displayed to the user on the "View" page.

```php
class Spec
{
    public $a;
    public $b;
    public $c;
}

class Calc
{
    public $spec;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->spec = new Spec();
    }

    function calcParameter()
    {
        $this->spec->c = $this->spec->a + $this->spec->b;
    }
}

class Plot
{
    public $calc;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->calc = new Calc();
    }

    function calcPlot()
    {
        $this->calc->spec->c = $this->calc->spec->a * $this->calc->spec->b;
    }
}


class Controller
{
    public $calc;
    public $plot;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->calc = new Calc();
        $this->plot = new Plot();
    }

    function doBusinessLogic()
    {

        //calc for local
        $this->calc->spec->a = 5;
        $this->calc->spec->b = 5;
        $this->calc->calcParameter();
        print "total is {$this->calc->spec->c}<br>\n";

        //later this format is used by JS to display computational results
        $plotJSON = json_encode($this->calc); 


        //calc for plot
        $this->plot->calc->spec->a = 7;
        $this->plot->calc->spec->b = 143;
        $this->plot->calcPlot();
        print "total is {$this->plot->calc->spec->c}<br>\n";

        //later this format is used by JS to display a plot
        $plotJSON = json_encode($this->plot); 
        print "
        <div id='plot' style='display:none'>$plotJSON</div>
        <script>
            var plot = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('plot').innerHTML);
            document.write('JS says - there are ' + plot.calc.spec.c + ' plot points<br>');
        </script>
        ";
    }  
}

//runs the above
(new Controller())->doBusinessLogic();
```

JS is used like so:

```
var plot = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('plot').innerHTML);
document.write('JS says - there are ' + plot.calc.spec.c + ' plot points<br>');
```

**Question**

I am under impression that the `Calc` class was not correctly placed (not designed properly), and as such, it is injected into various places just to do computations.  I am thinking that `Calc` should be a class with no parameters and that `Spec` should not be part of `Calc`.  And that `Calc` must only contain functions that do computations, and callers of `Calc` will supply their own data and receive results.  Thereby `Calc` will become a static library of functions to be used by others.   But then is this the best way?

How can I refactor this to minimize coupling?  Keeping in mind that JSON format is either to be preserved, or being mindful that any changes in code may require changes to JS code as well.

Before I go knee-deep refactoring this, the design I have now *works*.  Is there a need to refactor at all?  Just checking.

Comment: Plot's calcParameter doesn't look right. It refers to this->spec but it doesn't have a spec, it has a calc... Is that a mistake in the code?

Comment: thanks, fixed  (Plot function was not reachable)

Comment: Both `Calc` and `Spec` has same function ryt?

Comment: what's 'ryt'?  Spec has no functions, but Calc and Plot may have different functions.  Gonna change that..

Answer (score 0):

Okay, based on what I see so far, the Calc class should not exist at all. The `calcParameter` method should be a member of the Spec class.

The `calcPlot` method of `Plot` should also be a member of the Spec class (it deals entirely with Spec fields as currently written.) You still might want to keep `Plot` around though if it does other interesting things to its `Spec` object.

Like this:

```
class Spec {
    public $a;
    public $b;
    public $c;

    function calcParameter() {
        $this->c = $this->a + $this->b;
    }

    function calcPlot() {
        $this->c = $this->a * $this->b;
    }
}

class Plot {
    public $spec;

    function __construct() {
        $this->spec = new Spec();
    }

    function calcPlot() {
        $this->spec->calcPlot()
    }
}


class Controller {
    public $spec;
    public $plot;

    function __construct() {
        $this->spec = new Spec();
        $this->plot = new Plot();
    }

    function doBusinessLogic() {
        //spec for local
        $this->spec->a = 5;
        $this->spec->b = 5;
        $this->spec->calcParameter();
        print "total is {$this->spec->c}<br>\n";

        //later this format is used by JS to display computational results
        $plotJSON = json_encode($this->spec); 

        //spec for plot
        $this->plot->spec->a = 7;
        $this->plot->spec->b = 143;
        $this->plot->calcPlot();
        print "total is {$this->plot->spec->c}<br>\n";

        //later this format is used by JS to display a plot
        $plotJSON = json_encode($this->plot); 
        print "
        <div id='plot' style='display:none'>$plotJSON</div>
        <script>
            var plot = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('plot').innerHTML);
            document.write('JS says - there are ' + plot.spec.c + ' plot points<br>');
        </script>
        ";
    }  
}

//runs the above
(new Controller())->doBusinessLogic();
```

Comment: As a general rule... If you have a class that only has one field, and the class is not restricting the possible values of its field, then the class shouldn't exist.

Comment: thanks.  what do you mean by "restricting values of its field"?

Comment: So, in general, I see this as *move functions away from `Calc` and into their respective classes*, eventually getting rid of `Calc`.  I think that `Spec` can definitely use some functions that operate on its data, and also be renamed to better represent an object (as it becomes clearer in refactoring efforts).  For example in my full codebase `Spec` can represent products or motors and can be different for each specific product line.  I am not 100% sure that `Plot`-anything needs to be in `Spec`.  `Plot` is an entity that stores and does operations on graph data and can probably be decoupled.

Comment: For example if the class ensures its field is always greater than 0, or some other invariant that the field's class doesn't ensure.